# MPAndroidChart circles and numbers only for first and last points of a dataset

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am trying to generate a plot with MPAndroidChart. Specifically, a function which mainly depends on logarithms. For that reason I created the following for loop of data point entries (I am pretty sure this is not the best approach, but I decided to go for it)

```
yValues.add(new Entry(value3,value1));
float PointData = 100.0f;
for (int i=1 ; i<PointData ; i++){
    yValues.add( new Entry( value3+(i/PointData)*(value4-value3),value1+(value2-value1) * Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.log(value3+(i/PointData)*(value4-value3)/value3)/Math.log(value4/value3))) ) );
}
yValues.add(new Entry(value4,value2));
```

My problem is that I have to set

```
set1.setDrawCircles(false);
set1.setDrawValues(false);
```

otherwise my plot will be filled with circles and numbers. I would like though to be able to draw these two (circles and numbers) for just the first (defined by "yValues.add(new Entry(value3,value1));") and last (defined by "yValues.add(new Entry(value4,value2));") data set points. I spent a considerable amount of time but with no luck unfortunately. As a result, I would really appreciate if someone can help me towards solving this issue. I have also attached the whole java file in case someone wants to have a look at the code.

```
public class cyl_1plane_tempplot extends AppCompatActivity {

LineChart mChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cyl_1plane_tempplot);

    Intent localintent = getIntent();

    float value1 = localintent.getFloatExtra("key1", -1);
    float value2 = localintent.getFloatExtra("key2", -1);
    float value3 = localintent.getFloatExtra("key4", -1);
    float value4 = localintent.getFloatExtra("key5", -1);

    mChart = findViewById(R.id.cond_cyl_1layer_plot);

    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    mChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    float graph_excess_X = 10f;
    XAxis bottomAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    bottomAxis.setAxisMinimum(value3 - (value4 - value3)/graph_excess_X);
    bottomAxis.setAxisMaximum(value4 + (value4 - value3)/graph_excess_X);

    ArrayList<Entry> yValues = new ArrayList<>();
    yValues.add(new Entry(value3,value1));
    float PointData = 100.0f;
    for (int i=1 ; i<PointData ; i++){
        yValues.add( new Entry( value3+(i/PointData)*(value4-value3),value1+(value2-value1) * Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.log(value3+(i/PointData)*(value4-value3)/value3)/Math.log(value4/value3))) ) );
    }
    yValues.add(new Entry(value4,value2));

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();

    LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yValues, "Title");
    set1.setFillAlpha(110);
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_chart_color);
    set1.setColor(color);
    set1.setDrawCircles(false);
    set1.setDrawValues(false);
    set1.setLineWidth(3f);

    lineDataSets.add(set1);
    LineData data = new LineData(lineDataSets);
    mChart.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Oh buddy this can be done please follow instructions below:

1. Design an icon which you want to display instead of circle on first and last value.
2. Place that icon in drawable folder of you project.
3. Set draw values and circles to false. This will hide circles and values for every entry.

   ```
   set1.setDrawCircles(false);
   set1.setDrawValues(false);
   ```
4. Get your specific value on which you want to display your icon as:

   ```
   set1.getEntryForIndex(index).setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
   ```

In above line replace index with your entry index for example for first entry use 0. Also replace icon with your icon name in drawables.

Comment: This will work I tested that. Let me know if you need further assistance. Happy Coding :)

Comment: i want to show circle where user clicked on graph